# android - ViewPager with embeded view pager - how to turn off swipe listening on inner viewPager?

Tags: android

I have a viewpager that is embedded inside of another viewpager.

I created a class that subclasses ViewPager so that i can control swiping left to right. it looks like this:

```
public class SwippableViewPager extends ViewPager {

private boolean enabled;

public SwippableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.enabled = true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.enabled) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.enabled) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return false;
}
//can toggle swipping if not needed by UX
public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}
```

}

The last method there controls the swipping and it works great. But the problem i want the outer viewpager (the container) to be able to swipe left to right when user swipes on inner viewpager.  See the inner viewpager does not need to be swipped left to right because it has a tablayout for that. So imagine that i have a viewpager that is a container for a tablayout which is inside of a viewpager.  when user tries to swipe from left to right while touching the inner viewpager its taking the touch event and its not going to the outer viewpager.  how can i resolve this ?

Here is a image to better understand what i have built :

[image]

So i only want when user swipes from left to right that they can choose ViewP1,ViewP2,ViewP3. right now when use swipes while touching view1 it is taking the event.  I tried turning off setPagingEnabled method but doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code for your nested ViewPager it will make NestedViewPager ignore all touch events and pass them on to the parent view?

```
public class NonSwipeableViewPager extends ViewPager {

  public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
     super(context, attrs);

  }

  @Override
  public boolean canScrollHorizontally(int direction) {
     return false;
  }

}
```